# Function isn't working on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, that center some elements on page. But it not working on page first time load. It calls after page reload. How to fix it?

```
jQuery.fn.positionCenter = function() {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

$(".play_btn, .around").positionCenter();
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".play_btn, .around").positionCenter();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with binding also the `document.ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".play_btn, .around").positionCenter();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".play_btn, .around").positionCenter();
});
```

Comment: Souldn't it be `document.ready`/`window.load` and `window.resize`?

Comment: But his problem could even be from loading images (*hard to say without his html*) that are having a unknown size when only the DOM is ready, but not loaded. To be sure you could do `$(window).on("load, resize", ...`.

Answer (score -1):

I fix that problem.
I call after document load function.

Comment: Hello @StackOver! You seems to be new here. If you have find out an answer of your own, you should post a full example of the now working code with an discription of how it changed the behavor. Or in this case now, there is already an existing correct answer here. You should mark his answer as success to thank him for his effort.